# OL3: writing 'extended data' to KML

Tags: javascript, kml, openlayers-3

Unfortunately, during OL3's .writeFeatures(), **feature properties are NOT written to 'EXTENDED DATA' of a KML**.  The following:

```
var outFormat = new ol.format.KML(); 
var file = outFormat.writeFeatures(features);
```

creates a file ready for blob/export/whatever just fine, but feature name and all other properties are missing from the resulting KML file!!!

In other words, writing features from a source.Vector (or anything else)  to the KML format only seems to preserve the feature ID, all other properties/attributions are lost.

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd"><Placemark id="27"><Point><coordinates>-111.0580444335901,45.33284041773058</coordinates></Point></Placemark></kml>
```

**Is it possible to write properties to the extended data of the kml using OL3**, in lieu of building my own kml file from scratch?

...A reverse of the question/answer as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451364/ol3-extracting-extended-data-from-kml), but doesn't provide an answer...

Answer (score 0):

No this is currently not supported, but pull requests are welcome of course to add this. If you cannot write the code yourself, and you have budget, you can reach out to the companies that support OpenLayers.

Comment: If I write the code/ patch, is it of any use offering this back to the OL dev team?